# Merging output in R

Tags: r, aggregate

```
max=aggregate(cbind(a$VALUE,Date=a$DATE) ~ format(a$DATE, "%m") + cut(a$CLASS, breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14)) , data = a, max)[-1]
max$DATE=as.Date(max$DATE, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Sample Data :

```
DATE         GRADE    VALUE
2008-09-01     1        20
2008-09-02     2        30
2008-09-03     3        50
    .
    .
2008-09-30     2        75
    .
    .
2008-10-01     1        95
    .
    .
2008-11-01     4        90
    .
    . 
2008-12-01     1        70
2008-12-02     2        40
2008-12-28     4        30
2008-12-29     1        40
2008-12-31     3        50
```

My Expected output according to above table for only first month is :

```
 DATE         GRADE    VALUE
2008-09-30    (0,2]     75
2008-09-02    (2,4]     50
```

Output in my real data  :

```
                format(DATE, "%m")
1                        09
2                        10
3                        11
4                        12
5                        09
6                        10
7                        11



  cut(a$GRADE, breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14))        value
1                                                        (0,2] 0.30844444
2                                                        (0,2] 1.00000000
3                                                        (0,2] 1.00000000
4                                                        (0,2] 0.73333333
5                                                        (2,4] 0.16983488
6                                                        (2,4] 0.09368000
7                                                        (2,4] 0.10589335

          Date
1  2008-09-30
2  2008-10-31
3  2008-11-28
4  2008-12-31
5  2008-09-30
6  2008-10-31
7  2008-11-28
```

The output is not according to the sample data , as the data is too big . A simple logic is that there are grades from 1 to 10 , so I want to find the highest value for a month in the corresponding grade groups . Eg : I need a highest value for each group (0,2],(0,4] etc

I used an aggregate condition with function max and two grouping it by two columns Date and Grade . Now when I run the code and display the value of max , I get **3 tables** as output one after the other. Now I want to plot this output but i am not able to do that because of this .So how can i merge all these output ?

Comment: Do you mean merging output?

Comment: @user3923765.  Could you show your expected output

Comment: Because of the 2nd column name being too long, there is no space to print all columns next to each other. There is actually just one "table" (i.e. data frame). What do you get if you do `dim(max)` for example? (as a side note, `max` is a base R function, so it's best if you choose another name for your output)

Comment: I get 14,2 whereas I should get 14,3 ? Also I am not able to plot the values for different dates

Comment: @user3923765.  I am getting the expected output by year and month for the example data created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 library(dplyr)
 a %>%
 group_by(MONTH=format(DATE, "%m"), GRADE=cut(GRADE, breaks=seq(0,14,by=2))) %>%
 summarise_each(funs(max))

 #  MONTH GRADE       DATE VALUE
 #1    09 (0,2] 2008-09-30    75
 #2    09 (2,4] 2008-09-03    50
 #3    10 (0,2] 2008-10-01    95
 #4    11 (2,4] 2008-11-01    90
 #5    12 (0,2] 2008-12-29    70
 #6    12 (2,4] 2008-12-31    50
```

Or   using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
  setDT(a)[, list(DATE=max(DATE), VALUE=max(VALUE)), 
                         by= list(MONTH=format(DATE, "%m"),
                     GRADE=cut(GRADE, breaks=seq(0,14, by=2)))]
  #       MONTH GRADE       DATE VALUE
  #1:    09 (0,2] 2008-09-30    75
  #2:    09 (2,4] 2008-09-03    50
  #3:    10 (0,2] 2008-10-01    95
  #4:    11 (2,4] 2008-11-01    90
  #5:    12 (0,2] 2008-12-29    70
  #6:    12 (2,4] 2008-12-31    50
```

Or  using `aggregate`

```
  res <- transform(with(a, 
           aggregate(cbind(VALUE, DATE), 
             list(MONTH=format(DATE, "%m") ,GRADE=cut(GRADE, breaks=seq(0,14, by=2))), max)),
           DATE=as.Date(DATE, origin="1970-01-01"))
   res[order(res$MONTH),]
  # MONTH GRADE VALUE       DATE
  #1    09 (0,2]    75 2008-09-30
  #4    09 (2,4]    50 2008-09-03
  #2    10 (0,2]    95 2008-10-01
  #5    11 (2,4]    90 2008-11-01
  #3    12 (0,2]    70 2008-12-29
  #6    12 (2,4]    50 2008-12-31
```

#### data

```
 a <-  structure(list(DATE = structure(c(14123, 14124, 14125, 14152, 
   14153, 14184, 14214, 14215, 14241, 14242, 14244), class = "Date"), 
   GRADE = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), VALUE = c(20L, 
   30L, 50L, 75L, 95L, 90L, 70L, 40L, 30L, 40L, 50L)), .Names = c("DATE", 
  "GRADE", "VALUE"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Update

If you want to include `YEAR` also in the grouping

```
   library(dplyr)
   a %>% 
   group_by(MONTH=format(DATE, "%m"), YEAR=format(DATE, "%Y"), GRADE=cut(GRADE, breaks=seq(0,14, by=2)))%>%
  summarise_each(funs(max))
  #   MONTH YEAR GRADE       DATE VALUE
  #1     09 2008 (0,2] 2008-09-30    75
  #2     09 2008 (2,4] 2008-09-03    50
  #3     09 2009 (0,2] 2009-09-30    75
  #4     09 2009 (2,4] 2009-09-03    50
  #5     10 2008 (0,2] 2008-10-01    95
  #6     10 2009 (0,2] 2009-10-01    95
  #7     11 2008 (2,4] 2008-11-01    90
  #8     11 2009 (2,4] 2009-11-01    90
  #9     12 2008 (0,2] 2008-12-29    70
  #10    12 2008 (2,4] 2008-12-31    50
  #11    12 2009 (0,2] 2009-12-29    70
  #12    12 2009 (2,4] 2009-12-31    50
```

#### data

```
 a <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(14123, 14124, 14125, 14152, 
   14153, 14184, 14214, 14215, 14241, 14242, 14244, 14488, 14489, 
  14490, 14517, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14580, 14606, 14607, 14609
  ), class = "Date"), GRADE = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
  4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), VALUE = c(20L, 
  30L, 50L, 75L, 95L, 90L, 70L, 40L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 
  75L, 95L, 90L, 70L, 40L, 30L, 40L, 50L)), .Names = c("DATE", 
  "GRADE", "VALUE"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
  "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "21", "31", "41", "51", "61", 
   "71", "81", "91", "101", "111"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Also I have data of 5 years to work but , but when   i run this code, it just gives me values of months of last year . For eg - If I input the data from  2008-2013 . I only get 12 values for 12 months of 2013  whereas I am expecting 60 values, 12 for each year.

Comment: @user3923765.  In this case, you are only grouping by `MONTH` and `GRADE`, you may have to include `YEAR` also in the grouping.  Possibly by `format(DATE, "%Y")`. Not tested.

Comment: The results come same no matter whether I use %Y% or %M%

Comment: @user3923765.  DId you checked my new update.  BTW, here, I didn't change the `VALUE` column for 2008 and 2009

Answer (score 0):

Following code using base R may be helpful (using 'a' dataframe from akrun's answer):

```
xx = strsplit(as.character(a$DATE), '-')
a$month = sapply(strsplit(as.character(a$DATE), '-'),'[',2)
gradeCats = cut(a$GRADE, breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14))

aggregate(VALUE~month+gradeCats, data= a, max)
  month gradeCats VALUE
1    09     (0,2]    75
2    10     (0,2]    95
3    12     (0,2]    70
4    09     (2,4]    50
5    11     (2,4]    90
6    12     (2,4]    50
```